# Recommended approach to send a Maven SpringBoot project to another computer

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Say I have a Maven Springboot application that exposes REST APIs and is backed by a database (PostGRES). I want to share this project with another person so that it can be run on a different machine.

I should be able to run the project on a target machine and be able to hit the REST APIs.

I can think of multiple ways such as packing my code into a JAR, and dockerizing everything. This might be simple. But I want to understand the different options and a recommended approach to share the project so that it can be easily run on another computer.

[Update 1]: I am very familiar with Version control and Git. But in this scenario, I want to share my project on a Git repo with `README.md`. This way, the other person can just follow the readme and have my APIs running without having to install too many dependencies (Java, Springboot, Maven, PostGRES etc). Or maybe by just installing Maven and having everything else taken care of by Maven. So was trying to identify this flow. Or should I package everything into a container that is runnable on the other computer by just setting up docker?

The scenario is, say I want to showcase my work to a peer.

Comment: The project files are enough for running the Java code; what I do is add a docker-compose file for running anything else, like Postgres.

Comment: Do you use a version control ? A spring boot app is in the end single jar file ... ? Why Docker?

Comment: Yes, I missed to add about Git as that felt obvious. But you are right about Git/version control. Even with Git, I was trying to understand what I would do on the target machine to build my service. With this option, I would be needed Java and mvn on the target machine. Especially that I have a external database.

Comment: @SyncMaster Building is usually done on a special "CI" server. So if your code is on GitHub, try GitHub Actions, otherwise maybe Jenkins or GitLab CI.

Answer (score -1):

If your aim is to hit your rest apis, I would recommend to integrate SWAGGER in your project and use its UI swagger-ui.html to fire the apis's.

Its always recommended to add your project under version control for multiple reasons.